# Create SD Card for Emulator built from Android source code

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

I have built the Android source for the emulator.  I need to add sdcard to this emualtor.

Following are the commands, I use after the first full build:

```
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch 1
mmm packages/apps/MyApp/
adb sync
adb remount
```

However, I am unable to see the emulator in /mnt/sdcard path

What are the steps or commands, I need to use, in order to create an sdcard, when I use the emulator(with the commands above) built from Android source code.

I have been stuck with this issue for sometime. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

after executing

```
$ make -j4
```

execute

```
$ mksdcard -l mySdCard 1024M mySdCardFile.img
```

and then

```
$ emulator -sdcard mySdCardFile.img
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to the Android Virtual Device Manager, create your own or use an existing one and click the "Edit" button.

Then add some MB to your virtual SD Card.
[image]

Once started you can go to DDMS tab, then File Transfer tab and SDCard folder ;)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. But as I mentioned in the title, this is not an emulator related with AVD manager in any way. It is compiled and generated from Android source code.

Comment: Woops, I'm sorry then. I'm going to investigate a bit.